# VRP using Einstein Analytics?

Tags: einstein-analytics

I wanted to know if we could use Einstein Analytics to solve vehicle routing problems. For example, how to minimize the cost of a trip, recommend ideal routes for pick-up and drop, maximize the utilization of empty trucks. All these sound like they could be done with Stories.

I did a little digging around and found out that this is an NP hard problem and falls under Operations Research. There are other tools that do the scheduling and other things, I just want to know if it is possible to do the same with Einstein.

Any advice on this is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently I see no way that Einstein can use vehicle routing tools. Looking at:

http://www.einsteinanalyticslearningmap.com/

It may be possible to integrate it through:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_ai_prediction_builder_create.htm

But it seems to be more trouble than it is worth. Probably not the best answer but it is good to have another set of eyes seeing the same thing you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you so much Jeremy!